# Google payments, unexpected error for in-app purchase for Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, in-app-purchase

I am developing a Chrome Extension and I would like to allow users to make in-app purchases.

My extension is already deployed on Chrome store and the "in-app" purchase will be available on the new version (The one I am working on).

Well, I am struggling with the purchase: The Google Payment page shows up but I want to purchase the option, I receive a "unexpected error" and no way to get more details about this error. :-(

[Error I got when purchasing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kckma.png)

What I've done so far:
https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap

- I've imported the buy.js and implemented all the needed functions.
- I've set up a Google Merchant payment account (and even validated my account after receiving small amount of money sent by Google)

I've no idea of what's wrong... It seems it's really the very last part of the payment flow that fails, but no way to get more info about what's going on.

I've even activated Chrome debug logs but the data is not very useful (at least for me...)
Log covering the flow from the "Purchase button click", "Buy" button click, Error, and closing the window here:

```
[6668:6168:0112/001148:VERBOSE1:cross_device_promo.cc(180)] CrossDevicePromo::MaybeBrowsingSessionStarted; Ineligible for promo.
[6668:6168:0112/001148:VERBOSE1:cross_device_promo.cc(180)] CrossDevicePromo::MaybeBrowsingSessionStarted; Ineligible for promo.
[6668:6168:0112/001150:VERBOSE1:mutable_profile_oauth2_token_service_delegate.cc(216)] MutablePO2TS::RefreshTokenIsAvailable
[6624:7432:0112/001150:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(111)] Created context:
  extension id:           nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda
  frame:                  5A2F7394
  URL:                    
  context_type:           BLESSED_EXTENSION
  effective extension id: nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda
  effective context type: BLESSED_EXTENSION
[6624:7432:0112/001150:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(111)] Created context:
  extension id:           (none)
  frame:                  00000000
  URL:                    
  context_type:           UNSPECIFIED
  effective extension id: (none)
  effective context type: UNSPECIFIED
[6624:7432:0112/001150:VERBOSE1:dispatcher.cc(395)] Num tracked contexts: 2
[2160:3460:0112/001150:VERBOSE1:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3205)] GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil supported.
[6624:7432:0112/001150:VERBOSE1:htmlpluginelement.cpp(514)] OBJECT id="browser-plugin-8" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" Plugin URL: <null>
[6624:7432:0112/001150:VERBOSE1:htmlpluginelement.cpp(515)] Loaded URL: <null>
[2160:3460:0112/001150:VERBOSE1:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3205)] GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil supported.
[8032:536:0112/001150:INFO:systeminfo.cc(82)] Available number of cores: 4
[2160:3460:0112/001150:VERBOSE1:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3205)] GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil supported.
[2160:3460:0112/001150:VERBOSE1:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3205)] GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil supported.
[8032:536:0112/001150:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(111)] Created context:
  extension id:           nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda
  frame:                  2CE619DC
  URL:                    
  context_type:           CONTENT_SCRIPT
  effective extension id: nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda
  effective context type: CONTENT_SCRIPT
[8032:536:0112/001150:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(111)] Created context:
  extension id:           (none)
  frame:                  00000000
  URL:                    
  context_type:           UNSPECIFIED
  effective extension id: (none)
  effective context type: UNSPECIFIED
[8032:536:0112/001150:VERBOSE1:dispatcher.cc(395)] Num tracked contexts: 1
[8032:536:0112/001150:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(111)] Created context:
  extension id:           (none)
  frame:                  2CE619DC
  URL:                    
  context_type:           WEB_PAGE
  effective extension id: (none)
  effective context type: WEB_PAGE
[8032:536:0112/001150:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(111)] Created context:
  extension id:           (none)
  frame:                  00000000
  URL:                    
  context_type:           UNSPECIFIED
  effective extension id: (none)
  effective context type: UNSPECIFIED
[8032:536:0112/001150:VERBOSE1:dispatcher.cc(395)] Num tracked contexts: 2
[6668:6168:0112/001150:INFO:CONSOLE(325)] "did exec once", source: chrome-extension://nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda/craw_window.js (325)
[6668:6168:0112/001151:INFO:CONSOLE(176)] "[object XMLHttpRequest]", source: chrome-extension://nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda/craw_window.js (176)
[6668:6168:0112/001151:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "registered payment listener: 1484140311054", source: https://www.google.com/intl/en-US/chrome/blank.html (1)
[6668:6168:0112/001151:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "finished loading, start payment: 1484140311057", source: https://www.google.com/intl/en-US/chrome/blank.html (1)
[6668:6168:0112/001151:VERBOSE1:render_process_host_impl.cc(2402)] Blocked URL about:blank
[6668:6168:0112/001151:VERBOSE1:render_process_host_impl.cc(2402)] Blocked URL about:blank
[6668:6168:0112/001151:VERBOSE1:render_process_host_impl.cc(2402)] Blocked URL about:blank
[6668:6168:0112/001151:VERBOSE1:render_process_host_impl.cc(2402)] Blocked URL about:blank
[6668:6168:0112/001151:VERBOSE1:render_process_host_impl.cc(2402)] Blocked URL about:blank
[6668:6168:0112/001151:VERBOSE1:render_process_host_impl.cc(2402)] Blocked URL about:blank
[6668:6168:0112/001151:VERBOSE1:render_process_host_impl.cc(2402)] Blocked URL about:blank
[6668:6168:0112/001151:VERBOSE1:render_process_host_impl.cc(2402)] Blocked URL about:blank
[8032:536:0112/001151:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(111)] Created context:
  extension id:           (none)
  frame:                  2CE66704
  URL:                    
  context_type:           WEB_PAGE
  effective extension id: (none)
  effective context type: WEB_PAGE
[8032:536:0112/001151:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(111)] Created context:
  extension id:           (none)
  frame:                  00000000
  URL:                    
  context_type:           UNSPECIFIED
  effective extension id: (none)
  effective context type: UNSPECIFIED
[8032:536:0112/001151:VERBOSE1:dispatcher.cc(395)] Num tracked contexts: 3
[2160:3460:0112/001151:VERBOSE1:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3205)] GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil supported.
[6668:8968:0112/001151:VERBOSE1:mime_sniffing_resource_handler.cc(351)] To buffer: https://payments.google.com/payments/jslogs?message=1484140311084-hz693q2xx3xx-INFO-embedder%3Ano_id%3Aloading%20iframe%20with%20URL%20https%3A%2F%2Fpayments.google.com%2Fpayments%2Foauth%2Fembedded%2Fbuy_flow%3Fwst%3D1489999999999%26cst%3D1484140311072%26ipi%3Dhz693q2xx3xx%26hostOrigin%3DaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQ..%26mm%3De%26style%3Dpc%253D%2523FF0000%253Bac%253D%25230000FF%26ait%3DGAIA%26cn%3D%2524p_kpocjpn7rrfr0-%5Bhttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fintl%2Fen-US%2Fchrome%2Fblank.html%5D&zx=nm2hae7wm29o
[8032:536:0112/001151:VERBOSE1:dispatcher.cc(534)] Num tracked contexts: 2
[8032:536:0112/001151:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(111)] Created context:
  extension id:           (none)
  frame:                  2CE66704
  URL:                    
  context_type:           WEB_PAGE
  effective extension id: (none)
  effective context type: WEB_PAGE
[8032:536:0112/001151:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(111)] Created context:
  extension id:           (none)
  frame:                  00000000
  URL:                    
  context_type:           UNSPECIFIED
  effective extension id: (none)
  effective context type: UNSPECIFIED
[8032:536:0112/001151:VERBOSE1:dispatcher.cc(395)] Num tracked contexts: 3
[8032:536:0112/001151:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(120)] Destroyed context for extension
  extension id: 
  effective extension id: 
[8032:536:0112/001151:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(120)] Destroyed context for extension
  extension id: 
  effective extension id: 
[6668:6168:0112/001153:INFO:CONSOLE(326)] "[object MessageEvent]", source: chrome-extension://nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda/craw_window.js (326)
[6668:6168:0112/001153:INFO:CONSOLE(326)] "[object MessageEvent]", source: chrome-extension://nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda/craw_window.js (326)
[6668:8968:0112/001153:VERBOSE1:mime_sniffing_resource_handler.cc(351)] To buffer: https://payments.google.com/payments/jslogs?message=1484140313421-hz693q2xx3xx-INFO-embedded%3Ano_id%3Aiframe%20ready%20message%20sent-%5Bhttps%3A%2F%2Fpayments.google.com%2Fpayments%2Foauth%2Fembedded%2Fbuy_flow%3Fwst%3D1489999999999%26cst%3D1484140311072%26ipi%3Dhz693q2xx3xx%26hostOrigin%3DaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQ..%26mm%3De%26style%3Dpc%253D%2523FF0000%253Bac%253D%25230000FF%26ait%3DGAIA%26cn%3D%2524p_kpocjpn7rrfr0%5D&zx=3wrtmrrm4ztl
[6668:6168:0112/001153:INFO:CONSOLE(326)] "[object MessageEvent]", source: chrome-extension://nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda/craw_window.js (326)
[6668:8968:0112/001153:VERBOSE1:mime_sniffing_resource_handler.cc(351)] To buffer: https://payments.google.com/payments/jslogs?message=1484140313437-hz693q2xx3xx-INFO-embedder%3Ano_id%3Aiframe%20with%20URL%20https%3A%2F%2Fpayments.google.com%2Fpayments%2Foauth%2Fembedded%2Fbuy_flow%3Fwst%3D1489999999999%26cst%3D1484140311072%26ipi%3Dhz693q2xx3xx%26hostOrigin%3DaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQ..%26mm%3De%26style%3Dpc%253D%2523FF0000%253Bac%253D%25230000FF%26ait%3DGAIA%26cn%3D%2524p_kpocjpn7rrfr0%20is%20ready-%5Bhttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fintl%2Fen-US%2Fchrome%2Fblank.html%5D&zx=r8gnj6edd97y
[8032:536:0112/001154:VERBOSE1:htmlpluginelement.cpp(514)] EMBED Plugin URL: "https://clients2.google.com/gr/GrDataFetcher.swf"
[8032:536:0112/001154:VERBOSE1:htmlpluginelement.cpp(515)] Loaded URL: "https://clients2.google.com/gr/GrDataFetcher.swf"
[6668:6168:0112/001156:INFO:CONSOLE(326)] "[object MessageEvent]", source: chrome-extension://nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda/craw_window.js (326)
[6668:6168:0112/001158:VERBOSE1:cross_device_promo.cc(180)] CrossDevicePromo::MaybeBrowsingSessionStarted; Ineligible for promo.
[6668:6168:0112/001158:VERBOSE1:cross_device_promo.cc(180)] CrossDevicePromo::MaybeBrowsingSessionStarted; Ineligible for promo.
[6668:6168:0112/001158:INFO:CONSOLE(52)] "onPurchaseFailed", source: chrome-extension://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/scripts/buy.js (52)
[6668:6168:0112/001158:INFO:CONSOLE(59)] "Purchase failed. PURCHASE_CANCELED", source: chrome-extension://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/scripts/buy.js (59)
[6624:7432:0112/001158:VERBOSE1:dispatcher.cc(534)] Num tracked contexts: 1
[6624:7432:0112/001158:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(120)] Destroyed context for extension
  extension id: nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda
  effective extension id: nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda
[6624:7432:0112/001158:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(120)] Destroyed context for extension
  extension id: 
  effective extension id:
```

*(I've changed some ids in the code to get rid of potential personal infos)*

Do you have any clue what could be the problem? Any way to get more details about "backend" treatment that fails? Is there a more comprehensive documentation about what to configure and what to check?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I think I understand what was the issue... A developer can't buy his own in-app stuff...

I had to create a new Google account and try with this one... That worked just fine...